# Necessary and sufficient conditions for an event to happen infinitely often

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have some sequence of indicator random variables $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$, which are not independent. Let $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. What does the statement "$x_i$ happens infinitely often almost surely" say about $X_n$?

It is easy to get necessary conditions on $X_n$ for $x_i$ to happened infinitely often. For example, Borel-Cantelli gives us that $\mathbb{E}X_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, but this is not a necessary condition.

Ideally, if I knew the exact distribution of $X_i$ for every $i$, then I would be able to check some condition to know if the $x_i$'s happen infinitely often almost surely.

For example, suppose that I know that for every constant $C$, $\mathbb{P}[X_n > C] \to 1$, then can I conclude that $x_i$ happens infinitely often almost surely? If that condition is false, does that mean that $x_i$ almost surely happens only finitely often?

Comment: "What does the statement "$x_i$ happens infinitely often almost surely" say about $X$?" Which $X$? (There is no $X$ in your question.) If $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ then the statement "$x_i$ happens infinitely often almost surely"  is equivalent to $P(X=\infty)=1$.

Comment: @Did By $X$ I guess I mean $X_n$ in general (i.e. not for any specific $n$).

Comment: You mean, the *sequence* $(X_n)$? Then, some options are $P((X_n)\ \text{is unbounded})=1$ or $P(\sup X_n=+\infty)=1$ or $P(X_n\leqslant x)\to0$ for every $x$ or a number of equivalent statements.

Comment: @Did And those are necessary and sufficient?

Comment: Yes. (Can't you check they are?)